# Can't connect to MySQL database?

Tags: php, mysql, database, phpmyadmin, vagrant

I'm using a Vagrant box running Ubuntu 12.04. I can connect to phpMyAdmin and I can create tables an so fourth. But when I try to connect via Sequel Pro or try to connect my project to the database it won't connect. In Sequel Pro I get this error

`MySQL said: Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (61)`

I've tried other posts but nothing helped. The credentials are correct, as I have tried multiple times. I've also tried adding the port but it didn't help. As a heads up I'm using [this](http://www.dev-metal.com/install-php-login-nets-4-full-mvc-framework-login-script-ubuntu/) tutorial

Comment: this has nothing to do with credentials. If it was credentials, you'd get "access denied". this is a tcp/socket-level problem.

Comment: are you sure the msyql server is running? Have you tried connecting from the commandline? `>mysql -u root -p mydb`

Comment: @deanosaur — Since phpMyAdmin connects to it, it seems likely.

Comment: Does your Sequel Pro or client project run on the same machine as your MySQL database?

Comment: Yeah. It works fine when I tried the command. @deanosaur

Comment: Well I'm using Vagrant. But it when I use the browser I can sign into phpMyAdmin and it is functional. @sqlab

Comment: How does your URL for phpMyAdmin look like?

Comment: `http://127.0.0.1:8080/phpmyadmin/` also the `127.0.0.1` has been replace with `localhost` and my IP address. @sqlab

Comment: and how is your MySQL database name in phpMyAdmin and to where is the name connected

Comment: My database link? `http://10.0.0.6:8080/phpmyadmin/index.php?db=login&token=a24d855f97518fbd0617fd4c6303c9d3` and To where is the name connected?

Answer (score 1):

Sequel Pro is a Mac application. It won't run on Ubuntu. This implies that you aren't running it on your Vagrant VM.

127.0.0.1 is a loopback IP address. It means "This machine".

You need to:

1. Ensure your MySQL server is configured to allow you to connect to it over the network

   - MySQL access control includes the network addresses of machines that are allowed to connect
   - MySQL can be configured to listen over TCP/IP or just via a socket
2. Use the IP address of your Vagrant VM and not the OS X host machine

Comment: So I just tried my IP and it still won't connect. My IP address works fine with phpMyAdmin when I use the browser though.